# Update address fields relating to order via rest api in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

This code change order first and last name after order via rest api. I want to echo the billing first name where it says "asd".  olso i need to other meta related to billing information.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'digger_checkout_save_user_meta');

function digger_checkout_save_user_meta( $order_id ) {

   //$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  // $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    
      update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_first_name', 'asd' ); 
      update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_last_name','bsd' ); 
}
```

i try  this `update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_first_name', 'billing_first_name' );` but it doesnt work  :)  thx a lot for your replay.